# React is not connecting with other page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jsx

I have been trying to connect a simple thank you page with a random number as a reference id at the end of my webpage. My website works without any issue, but for some reason, the submit page at the end is just an empty white page without any text or color.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import { ThemeProvider as MuiThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";


export class submit extends Component {
  handleClick() {
    const min = 1000;
    const max = 10000;
    const rand = min + Math.random() * (max - min);
    this.setState({ random: this.state.random + rand });
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider>
        <>
          <Dialog
            open
            fullWidth
            maxWidth='sm'
          >
      
            <AppBar title="Success" /> 
            <h1>Thank You For Your Submission</h1>
            <p>If you need any further assistant mention your reference number: {this.state.random} </p>
          </Dialog>
         
        </>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
  
}

export default submit;
```

I am a little confused here, is it happening because of react-router or is it because of something wrong import? (I am importing material UI for the design and navbar)

Comment: I don't see any react-router code in your question. This appears to be an incomplete code example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Are you saying this `Submit` component isn't rendering its content?

Comment: It sounds like it will be an issue with your react router setup. Could you share the code for your routes please?

Comment: Sounds to me like you might have failed to return the component that is supposes to be rendered. Especially if you are using a function with brackets at the component prop. make sure you return. Kindly share the whole code